# Unable to compile serialization library dependancies into my AAR

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am importing a kotlin mpp project that I have working on iOS but on android I am getting a class not found exception

```
2020-03-19 17:08:59.905 25271-25387/com.test.testE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
    Process: com.test.test, PID: 25271
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlinx/serialization/internal/GeneratedSerializer;
```

my dependancies are

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.61")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serializationVersion")
}
```

It also works on my unit tests for android inside the library project. But when I import at as an aar it can't find the class. I am not using proguard any ideas what's wrong?

```
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-http-cio:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-http:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-http-cio-jvm:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-network:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-http-jvm:1.2.6@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-utils-jvm:1.2.6@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-io-jvm:0.1.16@jar
+--- io.ktor:ktor-utils:1.2.6@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-io:0.1.16@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:0.14.0@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.14.0@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.3.2-1.3.60@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-io-jvm:0.1.16@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.60@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.60@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.61@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-io:0.1.16@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.61@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu-common:0.14.1@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu:0.14.1@jar
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0@jar
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26@jar
\--- com.typesafe:config:1.3.1@jar
```

Environment

```
Kotlin version: 1.3.61
Library version: 0.14.0
Kotlin platforms: android,ios
Gradle version: 3.6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
The problem is AAR files get their dependencies from a pom file. when importing an AAR file it doens't have the references to the right libraries. Using maven-publish solved my issue without the need of duplicating the used repositories.

I had the same problem and I imported the missing dependencies in my build.gradle of my app. It solved the problem. My guess is the dependencies aren't fully included in the aar file. so let's say this is more of a hack then an actual solution. I had to do it to for other dependencies, I'm searching now for the cause of it.

```
dependencies {
//other dependencies for build.gradle (app)
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktor_version"
}
```

More info:
https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/1039#issuecomment-517660157